# отрисовка графики (пикселей) в реальном времени

Tags: python, графика

Привет, необходимо отрисовывать пиксели в окне в реальном времени, т.е мой алгоритм получит, например, список вида [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (xn, yn)], вызовет функцию обновления и у пользователя на экране эти пиксели изменят цвет. 
С огромной натяжкой это можно назвать рендерингом. Как реализовать такое на Python 3? Интересует именно вопрос с выводом. Было бы не плохо иметь кнопку сохранения результата

Comment: старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос. Пытались ли вы адаптировать для вашего случая примеры с [matplotlib animation](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/animation/index.html)? Что не получилось?